# Running Get-Service from C# host

Tags: c#, powershell

Here's a simple C# PowerShell host program which simply runs `Get-ChildItem` and displays the results on the console:

```
using System.Management.Automation;

using static System.Console;

namespace PsHostGetChildItem
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var result = PowerShell.Create().AddCommand("Get-ChildItem")
                .AddParameter("Path", @"c:\Windows")
                .AddParameter("Filter", "*.exe")
                .Invoke();

            foreach (var elt in result)
                WriteLine(elt);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what the output looks like:

[image]

If we setup a similar program which runs `Get-Service`:

```
using System.Management.Automation;

using static System.Console;

namespace PsHostGetService
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var result = PowerShell.Create().AddCommand("Get-Service").Invoke();

            foreach (var elt in result)
                WriteLine(elt);
        }
    }
}
```

it throws the following exception:

[image]

What's a good way to have the second program output the service names?

Comment: The code that works is using the cmd.exe environmental variables which include the PATH.  When running form a c# application there is no environmental variables so you must include the full path of where any files are located.  The other way to fix error is to put any executable in the same folder as the app.  VS will automatically copy any executable that is added to the project using "ADD AS EXISTING ITEM" which put an instruction into the .proj that will do the move.  Make sure you set the property in the "ADD AS EXISTING ITEM" to do the copying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code implicitly calls the `.ToString()` method of the `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController`  instances that `Get-Service` emits, and that `.ToString()` method is of member type `ScriptMethod`, which means that it executes a *script block*, i.e., a piece of *PowerShell* code, when called.

<sup>You can see this by interactively executing `Get-Service | Get-Member ToString`</sup>

**The problem is that calling `ScriptMethod` methods (as well as `ScriptProperty` properties) requires a PowerShell *runspace* to execute the *PowerShell code* in, and no runspace is available when you later access members (methods, properties) on objects returned from an `.Invoke()` call *in C# code*.**

**Workarounds**:

- (a) Call the member as part of *the PowerShell code* you execute so that its *value* is returned.
- (b) Avoid the script-based members in C# code and obtain the desired information differently.

---

#### (a) Calling the script-based members in PowerShell code:

```
using (var ps = PowerShell.Create(RunspaceMode.NewRunspace))
{
  foreach (var svcName in ps.AddScript("(Get-Service).ForEach('ToString')").Invoke()) 
  {
    Console.WriteLine(svcName);
  }
}
```

Note:

- The downside of this solution is that you only get the *names* of the services back, not rich objects describing them.
- The `.AddScript()` method is used in lieu of `.AddCommand()`, because it allows passing entire snippets of PowerShell code (script blocks) for execution.

  - Array method `.ForEach()`, to which the name of the method (`'ToString'`) to execute on each element is passed, requires PSv4+; in PSv3-, use the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet.

---

#### (b) Avoiding the script-based members in C# code:

In your case, `.ToString()` simply returns the value of the `.ServiceName` property, so you can get that property's value directly:

```
using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
  foreach (var svc in ps.AddCommand("Get-Service").Invoke()) 
  {
    Console.WriteLine(((dynamic) svc).ServiceName);

    // Alternatively, use an explicit cast from .BaseObject:
    // Console.WriteLine(
    //   ((System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController) svc.BaseObject).ServiceName
    // );
  }
}
```

Note the need to cast to `dynamic` in order to access the properties of the `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController` instances that wrapped by the `PSObject` instances returned by `.Invoke()`.

Alternatively, the wrapped object can also be accessed explicitly via the `PSObject`'s `.BaseObject` property, which allows casting to the real type.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a bit more for that to work:

```
foreach (string str in PowerShell.Create().AddScript("Get-Service").AddCommand("Out-String").Invoke<string>())
{
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Comment: Note that `Out-String` creates the same string representation that you would see in the PowerShell console, which isn't the same as (implicit) stringification in C# via `.ToString()`.
Such a representation is meant for display purposes only, not for later programmatic processing. Additionally, `Out-String` creates a single, multi-line string by default; you can pass `-Stream` to obtain an array of lines, but they are still based on the for-display representation.
Either way, access to the rich objects returned by `Get-Service` on the C# side is lost.

Comment: As an aside: There's no need for using `.AddScript()` here, given that you're adding the commands individually, though you could alternatively pass a single command string with `.AddScript("Get-Service | Out-String")`.